# How do I save the output of a Python generator into memory?

Tags: python, iterator

This question probably has a straightforward answer, but I'm not finding it.  I'm working with the Calendar class in Lib/calendar.py and there are several methods associated with that class that generate everything from date objects to tuples with year, month, day as integers, etc.  The one example below generates weekday index integers 0 - 6:

```
from calendar import Calendar

CurrentYear = Calendar()
iter1 = CurrentYear.iterweekdays()
for i in iter1:
    print(i)

# 0
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

`iter1` is an iterator that I can use to generate an index of weekdays without a problem.  Of course, once generated, there's nothing more to print if I run the loop again:

```
for I in iter1:
    print(i)

# no output
```

The documentation talks about using iterators quite a bit, but it's usually alongside iterables already defined in the code that can be iterated over.  But what if I don't have the iterable already defined?  How do I get the output of the generator into, say, a list container in memory so I can work with that list?

One thing I tried was this:

```
CurrentYear = Calendar()
wkday_list = []
iter1 = CurrentYear.iterweekdays()
for i in iter1:
    wkday_list[i] = iter1[i]
```

But, not knowing too much about iterators, I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Hopefully, it's clear what I'm trying to do from these snippets.  Is there a simple solution I can use to save output into memory that is generated by an iterator?

Comment: If you want to store week days into a list: `wday_list = list(CurrentYear.iterweekdays())`. I have a feeling that you don't have to do that, but without any context, I cannot be so sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is the value you want to save; you can write

```
wkday_list = []
for i in iter1:
    wkday_list.append(i)
```

or simply

```
wkday_list = list(iter1)
```

`list` itself will iterate over the iterator for your and build a list from the elements it gets back.

Answer (score 0):

You are using iter[i] instead of inter1[i]

Plus, you add an element to a list using the `append()` method, instead of wkday_list[i] as `wkday_list` has the length of 0 and using `wkday_list[1]` per say will break an outOfIndex error.

My approach :

```
from calendar import Calendar

CurrentYear = Calendar()
wkday_list = []
iter1 = CurrentYear.iterweekdays()
for i in iter1:
    wkday_list.append(i)

print(wkday_list)
```